# Log program runtime with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to log the runtime of a specific program and record the times in a file (plain text or Excel).

As an example of an output:

```
01.01.2018 notepad.exe Start: 06:30 End: 12:30 Duration: 6h
01.01.2018 notepad.exe Start: 14:00 End: 15:00 Duration: 1h
05.01.2018 ....
```

I have tried various things, but my knowledge just isn't enough and I'm not getting anywhere. There is no logging at any level cause it broke my output.

What I have now is:

```
$name = 'openvpn-gui'
$anzahl = $prozesse.Count

$läuft = $anzahl -gt 0
$prozesse = Get-Process -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Path ="$env:C\Log\Log.txt"

if ($läuft) {
    New-TimeSpan -Start($prozesse).StartTime
} else {
    "$name läuft nicht"
}
```

The background is that I want to document the use of openvpn. How many hours is the tool used per day?

And since I'm just getting used to PowerShell, I thought I could do it this way. But as described above, I very quickly reached my limits and have no clue to continue.

---

**OK! I managed to do something :)**

```
$start = (get-process openvpn-gui).StartTime
wait-process openvpn-gui                           
$end = Get-Date                                

$Runtime = $end - $start

Write-Host "Startzeit $start"
write-host "Endzeit $end"
write-host "$($Runtime.Hours) Stunden, $($Runtime.Minutes) Minuten, $($Runtime.Seconds) Sekunden"
```

2 errors still exist here: If openvpn-gui is not executed while the script is running, there is an error message

And how do I get that logged into a file? My attempts with Out-File -FilePath... cause a Log.txt to be created but without content

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have tried?

Comment: Code requests are off topic here, please take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then post a [mcve] of your code with a full explanation of what happens and what is output, which we can replicate in order to assist you.

Comment: Sorry! I should have put it differently

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add more details? Unless you are just curious, this very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). There are tools like AppLocker that might or might not be good solutions, but without knowing the real use case, it's all guesswork.

Comment: `$anzahl` and `$läuft` depend on `$prozesse` but defined before.

Comment: I edited my post.. The background is that I want to document the use of openvpn. How many hours is the tool used per day? And since I'm just getting used to Powershell, I thought I could do it this way.
But as described above, I very quickly reached my limits and have no clue to continue.

Comment: Just so save you future headaches in your coding career, don't use `ß,ü,ö,ä` in your code. Especially not for variable names. :)

Comment: I will remember that Paxz :)

Comment: This should get you off in the right direction: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/27/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-find-how-long-a-process-runs/

Comment: Edited the question with more info and a new code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shortcut which calls a script which logs the start time and then loads openvpn for you, then you could then call your script as openvpn will then be running. You might want to introduce a delay of a few seconds so openvpn loads before calling your script below.

```
$start = (get-process openvpn-gui).StartTime
wait-process openvpn-gui                           
$end = Get-Date                                

$Runtime = $end - $start

Write-Host "Startzeit $start"
write-host "Endzeit $end"
write-host "$($Runtime.Hours) Stunden, $($Runtime.Minutes) Minuten, $($Runtime.Seconds) Sekunden"
```

You can write variables out to file like this

```
$StartTime = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
$MyFilenamePath = "c:\test\OpenVPNStart$StartTime.txt"
$StartTime | sc $MyFilenamePath
```